# How to set Custom View in TabHost.TabSpec Indicator and still show the bottom strip

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabs

I am using TabHost and ViewPager to show tabs. For each tab i want to show a custom view as its indicator. 
I know i can do this using TabSpec.setIndicator

```
    TabHost.TabSpec spec    =   mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1");
    spec.setIndicator(createTabView(R.drawable.tab1, "name_of_tab1"));

//Below method returns a view to be set as the indicator of the tab
    private View createTabView(final int id, String tab_name) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tabs_icon, null);
        ImageView imageView =   (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_icon);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(id));
        TextView tabName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_name);
        tabName.setText(tab_name);
        return view;
    }
```

But after i set this , the bottom tab strip (generally blue colored one ) is gone .I want to set a custom view but i also want to show the tab strip to highlight which tab is currently selected.
Please help me how to achieve this .I do not want to use PageStrip as it is available in API level 21 or above . But my application supports devices with API level 16 or above .

Comment: Did you get the solution for this problem? I am facing same problem here. If done , please share your sample code. Thank you.

Comment: I could not find a solution . I switched to using TabLayout instead of TabHost

Comment: I ended up using this pattern. [here] (http://joshclemm.com/blog/custom-android-tabs/)